# Override action_controller.allow_forgery_protection for specific integration test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, integration-testing

I have a rails3 app that uses `protect_from_forgery` in my base application controller. I'm using `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` and want to ensure that authenticity tokens are present during certain integration tests.

I don't want every functional test that executes a post to have to pass up an `authenticity_token`, so my `test.rb` file specifies:

```
  config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection    = false
```

as the rails docs suggest.

For integration tests, however, I'd love to make sure that my forms are sending up the authenticity token properly. I cannot find any way to do this without changing the setting globally in `config/environments/test.rb`

If all my forms were generated with `form_for` I'd be content to trust that rails handles this, but I use ExtJS and have a number of ExtJS Forms that need to specify this manually, so I really should test that the plumbing is all working.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can simply change the value in your integration test setup:

```
require 'test_helper'

class MyCrunchyIntegrationTest < ActionController::IntegrationTest
  fixtures :all

  def setup
    ActionController::Base.allow_forgery_protection = true
  end

  def teardown
    ActionController::Base.allow_forgery_protection = false
  end

  test "how awesome my application is" do
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: But this doesn't reset it for the next test! IMO gmcnaughton's answer is better.

Comment: True. Edited to reset the value in `teardown` method. Using a block as @gmcnaughton suggested may be better for more granular control, though.

Answer (score 12):

Helper method that enables forgery protection temporarily for a block:

```rb
def with_forgery_protection
  orig = ActionController::Base.allow_forgery_protection
  begin
    ActionController::Base.allow_forgery_protection = true
    yield if block_given?
  ensure
    ActionController::Base.allow_forgery_protection = orig
  end
end

with_forgery_protection do
  # code in here will require csrf token
end
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a RSpec version of @gmcnaughton's solution.

This goes in `spec_helper.rb`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.around(:each, :with_csrf_protection) do |example|
    orig = ActionController::Base.allow_forgery_protection

    begin
      ActionController::Base.allow_forgery_protection = true
      example.run
    ensure
      ActionController::Base.allow_forgery_protection = orig
    end
  end
end
```

Then you write the tests like:

```
it "foo", with_csrf_protection: true do
  # …
end
```

Or, depending on your RSpec settings:

```
it "foo", :with_csrf_protection do
  # …
end
```

Comment: This can get overwritten by the included `around` filter in `lib/rspec/rails/example/controller_example_group.rb:188`, so is more suited to request specs than controller specs